# Why is Excel not calculating the cube root as the cube root?

Tags: excel, math, formula, cube

I have a suspicion Excel is calculating exponents that are repeating decimals represented as a fraction (e.g. 1/3) differently than ones that don't have repeating decimals (e.g. 1/2). It is preventing me for a formula that finds perfect cubes in a list of numbers.

Column A lists numbers 1 to 100.

Column B has the following formula (starting with row 5):

```
=IF($A5^(1/2)-ROUND($A5^(1/2),0)=0,1,0)
```

This should return "1" if the number in column A is a perfect square, like 1, 4, 9, etc. and does so correctly. This other formula I originally wrote also works: `=IF(SQRT($A8)-ROUND(SQRT($A8),0)=0,1,0)`.

Column C has the following formula (starting with row 5):

```
=IF($A5^(1/3)-ROUND($A5^(1/3),0)=0,1,0)
```

Note that it is the exact same as the perfect square identifying formula, except there is a 3 where there was a 2. This is *not* returning a "1" for perfect cubes like 8, 27, 64. etc. (but does return a "1" for the number 1).

Can anyone help me correct this?

Comment: This is strange. If you calculate the first and second part separately, then set them equal you get `TRUE` but when you subtract them and test if =0 you get `FALSE`

Comment: So my current workout is this, but I don't know why I need a workaround at all: `=IF(INT($A5^(1/3))-ROUND($A5^(1/3),5)=0,1,0)`

Comment: not sure. I tried with `=POWER(A3,1/3)-ROUND(POWER(A3,1/3),0) = 0` to same result

Comment: Seems like floating point error.

Comment: Yup you're right, it's been a while since I've been in math class... will edit original post.

Comment: Can't you replace `$A5^(1/3)-ROUND($A5^(1/3)` with `$A5 - ROUND($A5^(1/3))^3`?

Comment: Yes that works too. Conceptually it's the same thing, but in practice only this one works.

Comment: See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result).  If you examine the underlying xml, you will see that Excel is calculating `A1^(1/3)` as `1.9999999999999998`. The article explains why, and suggests some work arounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for not knowing how to pick a comment as an answer, so I aggregated the helpful comments and am posting them as an answer.

Main Explanation:
See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result). If you examine the underlying xml, you will see that Excel is calculating A1^(1/3) as 1.9999999999999998. The article explains why, and suggests some work arounds. – Ron Rosenfeld

Workaround I picked:
Can't you replace `$A5^(1/3)-ROUND($A5^(1/3)` with `$A5 - ROUND($A5^(1/3))^3?` – r3mainer

Thanks all!